# Detect handleChange of grouped questions - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a form that contains several questions. Some of the questions contains a group of subquestions.

```
{
  (this.props.moduleDetails.questions[questionInfo].question_group && this.props.moduleDetails.questions[questionInfo].has_grouped_questions === 1) ?
    <div className="sub-questions">
      {
        (this.props.moduleDetails.questions[questionInfo].question_group )  ?
          <span>
            { this.renderQuestionGroup(questionInfo) }
            <input type="button" onClick={(e) => { this.addQuestionGroup(questionInfo) }} value="Add" className="btn"/>
          </span>
          : null
      }
    </div>
    : null
}
```

As you can see, renderQuestionGroup is the method that displays the sub-questions.

```
renderQuestionGroup(questionInfo) {
    let input = [];

    input = this.display(questionInfo)
    return input;
  }

  display(questionInfo) {
      let input = [];
      this.state && this.state.groupedQuestions && this.state.groupedQuestions[questionInfo] && this.state.groupedQuestions[questionInfo].map(
        (qInfo, qIndex) => {
                  if(qInfo !== undefined) {

                    Object.keys(qInfo).map(
                      (questionInfo, index) => {
                        input.push(<QuestionAnswers
                                     questionInfo={qInfo[questionInfo]}
                                     generateStepData={this.props.generateStepData}
                                     userEnteredValues={this.props.formValues}
                                     key={qInfo[questionInfo].module_question_id+qIndex}
                                     groupIndex={qIndex}
                                />)
                  });
                }
      });
     return input;
  }
```

Subquestions (a group of questions) are placed in state during the componentDidUpdate.

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState, snapshot) => {
    console.log('prevProps----------->', prevProps);
    console.log('this.props----------->', this.props)
    if (prevProps !== this.props) {
      let questions = this.props.moduleDetails.questions,
          sgq       = {};

      Object.keys(questions).map((qId) => {
        sgq[qId] = (this.state.groupedQuestions[qId]) ? this.state.groupedQuestions[qId] : [];
        let answerId = this.props.formValues[qId],
            questionObj = questions[qId],
            groupedQuestions = [];
        if(questionObj.has_grouped_questions == 1 && answerId != null && (this.state.groupedQuestions != null)) {
          groupedQuestions = questions[qId].question_group[answerId];


          let loopCount = this.getLoopCount(groupedQuestions);

            for(let i=0; i<loopCount; i++) {
              sgq[qId].push(groupedQuestions);
            }
        }
      });
      this.setState({groupedQuestions: sgq});
    }
  }
```

This works well and the questions get loaded correctly initially. The problem is that during every handleChange event, the method componentDidUpdate is getting triggered which eventually leads to rendering questions again.

I dont want the componentDidUpdate method to invoke during the handlechange event. Any idea on how to fix this?

PS: My idea was to compare  prevProps and this.props. If both are not same, it will be handle change event. But the issue is that  if i remove the condition

```
if (prevProps !== this.props) {
  ...
}
```

I am getting an infinite loop during initial load. So what i need is as follows.

- Detect handleChange inside componentDidUpdate method.
- Questions to render correctly initially. Currently i am getting an infinite loop if i remove the if (prevProps !== this.props) { ...} condition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate` is triggered on each change of the state, this is why you can get infinite loops when you set the state there.

If your new data is coming from  from `props` then move this logic to `getderivedstatefromprops` (or `componentWillReceiveProps` if you are using lower version of react below v16.3).

[getderivedstatefromprops](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

[componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

As for handle change just set the state inside the handler, no need to listen for changes in `componentDidUpdate`.